# re-entrancy vulnerability - "Potential violation of Checks-Effects-Interaction pattern"

Tags: vulnerability

I am getting the error "Potential violation of Checks-Effects-Interaction pattern in Test.treasuryLock(address,uint256): Could potentially lead to re-entrancy vulnerability."
But I am not really sure why, I even add a require check for rentrancym, but I still get the same error.
Do you have any ideea?

```
bool isTransferring = false;
// Lock treasury
// This function may be called only by the token contractor address

event treasuryLockEvent(address,uint256);
function treasuryLock(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 amount
) public returns(
    string memory, 
    uint256, 
    string memory, 
    address
    ) {

    require(isTransferring == false, "Rentrancy Detected");
    isTransferring = true;
    require( _beneficiary != address(0), "Please insert the beneficiary address.");
    address from = _msgSender();
    require( from == getTokenAddressContractor(), "Only token address contractor can lock Treasury.");
    require(from != burnAddress, "Burn address can not lock treasury." );

    if (_contractLink[_beneficiary] == newContract)
        _contractLink[_beneficiary] = new LockTest(token,_beneficiary);

    _transfer(from, _contractLink[_beneficiary].getAddress() ,amount);
    _lockedTreasury[_beneficiary]=balanceOf(_contractLink[_beneficiary].getAddress());
    isTransferring = false;
    emit treasuryLockEvent(_beneficiary,amount);
     return (
        "Existing contract received amount:",
        amount,
      "Beneficiary address:",
      _beneficiary
    );
    
}
```

Comment: What tool are you using to display those errors? Some tools implement just a basic algorithm that searches for certain patterns and fail to understand what the code is doing. I'd check with an auditor and disable the warning if the tool allows it.

Comment: Hello,

To compile the code I am using remix.
Is something wrong with my sintax:
require(isTransferring == false, "Rentrancy Detected");
    isTransferring = true;
do ..
    isTransferring = false;